# TOP 5 and aggregate rest all to 'Others' in Cognos 10 report studio

Tags: report, cognos-10

I need to display top 5 clients (based on revenue) and aggregate rest all clients to just a single row 'Others'  in a list report

C1 100

C2 150

C3 200

C4 250

C5 300

Others 5000

Let me know how I can achieve this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cognos?
What RDBMS?

I developed a solution for Cognos 11.0.7 and Microsoft SQL Server 2016.  My solution uses two queries:  Query1 gets the data, Query2 aggregates the data the way you want.

In Query1, add a Data Item named Rank that uses the rank() function.  `rank([Revenue])`

Query2 uses all of the columns in Query1.

In Query2, change the Client column to

```
case
    when [Query1].[Rank] < 6
        then [Query1].[Client]
    else 'Other'
end
```

Here's a code sample using the GO Sales (query) sample package.  This was done in Cognos 11.0.7, but it should work in Cognos 10.x.x if you change the version numbers in the first line of the report spec.

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/14.1/" useStyleVersion="11.4" expressionLocale="en-us">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <page name="Page1">
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                    <pageBody>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                        <contents>
                            <list horizontalPagination="true" refQuery="Query2" name="List2" rowsPerPage="1000">
                                <noDataHandler>
                                    <contents>
                                        <block>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                    <style>
                                                        <CSS value="padding:10px 18px;"/>
                                                    </style>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </block>
                                    </contents>
                                </noDataHandler>
                                <style>
                                    <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                    <defaultStyles>
                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                    </defaultStyles>
                                </style>
                                <listColumns>
                                    <listColumn>
                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="City"/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                        <listColumnBody>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="City"/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </listColumnBody>
                                    </listColumn>
                                    <listColumn>
                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                        <listColumnBody>
                                            <style>
                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lm"/>
                                                </defaultStyles>
                                            </style>
                                            <contents>
                                                <textItem>
                                                    <dataSource>
                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Quantity"/>
                                                    </dataSource>
                                                </textItem>
                                            </contents>
                                        </listColumnBody>
                                    </listColumn>
                                </listColumns>
                                <sortList>
                                    <sortItem refDataItem="rank"/>
                                </sortList>
                                <listOverallGroup>
                                    <listFooter>
                                        <listRows>
                                            <listRow>
                                                <rowCells>
                                                    <rowCell>
                                                        <contents>
                                                            <textItem>
                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                    <staticValue>Overall</staticValue>
                                                                </dataSource>
                                                            </textItem>
                                                            <textItem>
                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                    <staticValue> - </staticValue>
                                                                </dataSource>
                                                            </textItem>
                                                            <textItem>
                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                    <staticValue>Total</staticValue>
                                                                </dataSource>
                                                            </textItem>
                                                        </contents>
                                                        <style>
                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="if"/>
                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                        </style>
                                                    </rowCell>
                                                    <rowCell>
                                                        <contents>
                                                            <textItem>
                                                                <dataSource>
                                                                    <dataItemValue refDataItem="Total(Quantity)"/>
                                                                </dataSource>
                                                            </textItem>
                                                        </contents>
                                                        <style>
                                                            <defaultStyles>
                                                                <defaultStyle refStyle="is"/>
                                                            </defaultStyles>
                                                        </style>
                                                    </rowCell>
                                                </rowCells>
                                            </listRow>
                                        </listRows>
                                    </listFooter>
                                </listOverallGroup>
                            </list>
                        </contents>
                    </pageBody>
                </page>
            </reportPages>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2013-01-08T15:30:33.117Z"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO Sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
    <queries>
        <query name="Query1">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[City]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="attribute"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales].[Quantity]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="1"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="fact"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="rank">
                    <expression>rank([Quantity])</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItemListSummary refDataItem="Quantity" aggregateMethod="total" name="Total(Quantity)"/>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query2">
            <source>
                <queryRef refQuery="Query1"/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>case
    when [Query1].[rank] &lt; 6
        then [Query1].[City]
    else &apos;Other&apos;
end</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="total" name="Quantity">
                    <expression>[Query1].[Quantity]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="rank">
                    <expression>[Query1].[rank]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItemListSummary refDataItem="Quantity" aggregateMethod="total" name="Total(Quantity)"/>
            </selection>
        </query>
    </queries>
</report>
```